How to disable bun.js cache for node_modules?
I changed javascript source code in one of node_modules dependencies, for debug purposes.
But when I ran the main script bun run main.ts that uses this dependency via require('some_dependency'), it was as if there were no changes at all.
Seems like bun.js somehow cache it, how to run main.ts with disabled cache, so the changes to dependency sources would be picked up?
UPDATE I found one way, use relative path require('./node_modules/some_dependency'). Still would like to know if there's some bun option to do that.
